# How can I deserialize Ruby-serialized YAML data in PHP?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I'm a new guy in PHP and I want to deserialize Ruby serialized YAML data in PHP.

Hash anyone done that yet?

Ruby code:

```
class CustomField < ActiveRecord::Base
   serialize :possible_values
end
```

In Rails, I used the below code to retrieve data from a MySQL database:

```
  cf = CustomField.find(1).possible_values.to_s
```

and I can retrieve the result:

```
  [\"文字\", \"スタイル\", \"入力チェック\"]
```

In cakephp, the retrieved result is:

```
--- 
- !binary |
  5paH5a2X

- !binary |
  44K544K/44Kk44Or

- !binary |
   5YWl5Yqb44OB44Kn44OD44Kv
```

Comment: Do you mean this? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-parse-file.php

Comment: [YAML is a standard](http://www.yaml.org/). Both Ruby and PHP have YAML compliant parsers/generators. Use those and your data should move round-trip correctly. If you're moving it via HTTP, you probably should use JSON though, as it's more web-oriented.

Comment: @theTinMan: Even though YAML is standardized you can still end up with non-portable nonsense like `"--- !ruby/object:Some::Class \n..."` in your YAML (especially if you're using a nasty hack like `serialize`). So yeah, JSON is a much better choice.

Comment: Regex patterns can be a problem too. I just convert them to a string, which serializes nicely, then load them in and return them to their regex-state in whatever other language I'm using. That's worked well with Perl and Python.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everybody.

I resolved it myself.
In rails, if you define serialize attribute like below

```
class CustomField < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :possible_values
end
```

Rails will save that serialized yaml and base64_encoded data into DB.

So, In php

First, I parsed yaml data that retrieve from db.

```
$base64_encoded_possible_values = yaml_parse($result[0]["CustomField"]["possible_values"]);
/*
  array
  0 => 5paH5a2X,
  1 => 44K544K/44Kk44Or
  ...
*/
```

Before you can use yaml_parse method, you must install [yaml php extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/yaml.installation.php).

In my case, I download the [php_yaml.dll](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/yaml/1.1.1/php_yaml-1.1.1-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip) and put it into C:\xampp\php\ext, then add below line into C:\xampp\php\php.ini.

```
extension=php_yaml.dll
```

Second, decode that value.

```
base64_decode($base64_encoded_possible_values[0]);//文字
```